# Unknown crash reason "nativePollOnce"

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

I've had moderate success with using HockeyApp to monitor exceptions and crashes for the most part but for those situations that don't report any C# code is when I have a hard time.

Both the following crashes
[image]
have the same crash log:
[image]

But Google searches for both Unable to create layer for Platform_DefaultRenderer and nativePollOnce yield 0 helpfull links.

Any help with this matter would be appreciated since as you can see it has been causing a lot of problems.

Thanks in advance!

Diogo